# Is it possible to get the actual type from a stack trace?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, stack-trace

I'm writing an ExceptionFactory class, using `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace`.

```
 var trace = new StackTrace(1, true);
 var frames = trace.GetFrames();
 var method =  frames[0].GetMethod();
```

Now, for classes

```
class Base
{
   public void Foo()
   {
      //Call ExceptionFactory from here
   }
} 
class A : Base {}

//...

var x = new A();
x.Foo();
```

`method.DeclaringType` would return `typeof(Base)`. However, I need `typeof(A)`. Is it possible to get somehow?

`method.ReflectedType` doesn't work either.

Comment: What exactly is an ExceptionFactory?

Comment: It parameterizes a custom exception based on the place of the calling (e.g.: Module, custom attributes on calling type, etc) - and this is why I need the actual type, so I can query class A for attributes instead of class Base

Comment: Why doesn't ReflectedType work? What does it return?

Comment: Base. Same as Declaring Type.

Comment: @TDaver: just keep in mind that StackTrace may not contain all the frames you expect, as the JIT can optimize methods calls.

Comment: Yeah, I already had a question about that :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849709/stack-trace-for-logging-in-net/4849946#4849946

Comment: Martinho is correct. And apart from this, getting parameters from stack frames is not really possible in a generic way, so that you'll likely not be able to achieve what you want. This is especially true for release builds. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076/obtain-parameter-values-from-stackframe-in-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, since the method is actually declared on `Base`. As long as the method is not overridden, you always get the same `MethodInfo` instance for the method independent of whether you query it on the base class or on the derived class.

But why do you need the other type in the first place? There may be another solution to your problem, that's why I'm asking this.

Comment: My base class contains basic operations (like delete, insert, etc). If anything is faulty, I want to raise an exception, with finding out the operation type (insert,delete,etc), layer (business logic, data access ,etc), and module of the location of the error. However if the problem is in class A, which is in module "Project1", and base is in "Framework", I want the module to be "Project1", but since the exception was raised in Base, I'll get "Framework"...

Comment: If the members defined in the "Framework" are virtual or abstract and then overridden by the "Project1" classes, you'll get the information you want...

Comment: I've decided that on non-overriden cases, I'll provide the exceptionFactory with the required data (Module and actual ClassName) myself. If none provided, it will search the StackTrace.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just use `this.GetType()`. That will return the subclass. So the following code snippet should print "A".

```
public void Foo()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(this.GetType().ToString());
}
```

Comment: From my understanding, the `ExceptionFactory` is a separate class which relies on the stack trace to generate the exception; so it is likely that there is no "this" available.

Comment: Exactly, although if there are no other solutions it will take a Type parameter (however that wouldn't be very nice, because it will only correspond with the first level of the trace, so it's not a global solution...)

Comment: This will work *as long as you are inside the method* or at least within the same type. When you make a call to a method within another type, this will (obviously) no longer be an option, regardless of whether the invoked helper method is static or not.

Comment: @TDaver could you not pass in "this" to the ExceptionFactory constructor?

Comment: ExceptionFactory is static, there was no reason to create a new instance just for one "throw"...

Comment: @TDaver I don't think it's possible in that case using StackTrace.  You could use some unsafe code to try to unpeel the stack but as Martinho commented above you will get all sorts of things missing in the stack as a result of JIT optimization.