# Can I avoid this copy&paste of code?

Tags: c#, optimization

I've got two functions, and their contents are very similar.

```
// mock-up code

bool A() {
    while(1000000) {
        // 3 lines of A() specific code
        // 15 lines of shared code, pasted in
        // 1 lines of A() specific code
    }
}
bool B() {
    while(1000000) {
        // 2 lines of B() specific code
        // 15 lines of shared code, pasted in
        // 2 lines of B() specific code
    }
}
```

I'd like to not have the 15 lines of shared code pasted into both functions (because those lines are pretty complicated, and if I change that code later on, I don't want to have to remember to change it in both places).

If I put the 15 lines into a separate function, I take a significant performance hit (the JIT refuses to inline it; likely due to structs in the parameter list and/or 'complicated' flow control elements).

Is there another way, or am I out of luck?

Comment: A question for Hans Passant perhaps? What is the return type of your separate function?

Comment: split into small methods and increase reusability

Comment: @JeremyChild or Jon Skeet

Comment: Maybe try another C# implementation, i.e. http://mono-project.com/ or wait till your C# implementation  (i.e. compiler & runtime) gets improved. Or use some textual preprocessor.

Comment: Can you put the common code in a macro?

Comment: @Barmar C# only has "defined or not defined" macros, they don't expand to anything

Answer (score 0):

This 'significant' performance hit you're talking about is much less significant than what you think.

If it is so significant, You can try to tell to the JIT compiler to inline it using [MethodImplOptions Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions%28v=VS.110%29.aspx), Though he should do it if the method is not virtual. [For more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660004/when-is-a-method-eligible-to-be-inlined-by-the-clr).

Example (From MSDN) :

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class Utility
{
   [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] 
   public static string GetCalendarName(Calendar cal)
   {
      return cal.ToString().Replace("System.Globalization.", "").
                 Replace("Calendar", "");
   }
}
```

Comment: The last answer seems to have got deleted, so I'll post again here. A() is [Eric Lippert's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/) A* Pathfinder, and B() is a slightly modified version that resembles Dijkstra's algorithm. Currently the performance is competitive to C++ implementations of these algorithms (which was a design goal). However, with the additional of a non-inlined function call, the performance is not competitive.

Comment: You cannot force a method to inline in C# (as you can in C++), AggressiveInlining *might* inline it, might not, or worse (might vary across different hardware). Sadly, it's not even an option for me, a requirement of the code is .NET Framework 2.0 compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

Let's not look for something too involved, what about that? Not so clean, but that may be the price you have to pay to have both non-reproduction and performance:

```cs
boolean AorB (boolean flagA) {
    while(1000000) {
        if (flagA) {
            // 3 lines of A() specific code
        }
        else {
            // 1 line of B() specific code
        }

        // 15 lines of shared code, pasted in

        if (flagA) {
            // 2 lines of A() specific code
        }
        else {
            // 2 lines of B() specific code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I took a stab at that design using `goto` statements. My rationale was that with `goto` it might be possible to prevent the need to assess whether `AorB` is functioning as `A()` or `B()` on *each iteration* of the `while` loop. I wasn't successful.

Comment: Why `goto`? It will make your code even more awful to read. Start with exactly what I posted to see how it goes. If you like it you can think of the way you want to write it. And don't try to optimize to the point of sparing a `if` by `while` iteration, it does not make sense: the .NET VM might figure out things by itself and maybe what you think is not what happens.