# Why string.Contains performs better than string.IndexOf?

Tags: c#, string, performance, benchmarking, .net-4.6.2

I am trying to optimize a method.

Here is the original method:

```
private const string Separator = "::";
private char[] SeparatorChars = Separator.ToCharArray();

public string GetSubName(string name)
{
    if (name.Contains(Separator))
    {
        return name.Split(SeparatorChars)[0];
    }
    
    return "INVALID";
}
```

if `name` doesn't contain `::`, return `INVALID` else return the first element in the array by generated by `Split` with `::`.

I have wrote the following optimized method:

```
public string GetSubNameOpt(string name)
{
    var index = name.IndexOf(Separator, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        return name.AsSpan().Slice(0, index).ToString();
    }

    return "INVALID";
}
```

The goal was to omit the second O(N) iteration over the string in order to split it in case it contains the `::` substring.

I benchmarked both method using BenchmarkDotNet and here are the results
[image]

Now.. while, as expected, the Optimized method is better in time and memory in the "name contains :: case" due usage of AsSpan and removing of 1 O(N) iteration of the string, it was surprise to me that the Non Optimized method was better for the INVALID case.

**EDIT**
Running with a non empty, not containing `::` case.
[image]

Again, the Optimized method is slower...

Can you explain what is causing this behavior?

Comment: Which .NET version did you use?

Comment: You know you don't need to use `Span` to get a contiguous substring right?

Comment: Also note that the `Split(SeparatorChars)` version is wrong.  Try an input of `AB:CDE::FGH`.   `Split(Separator)` would be better, except it didn't exist in 4.6.2.

Comment: @KlausGütter: net4.6.2 - I've updated my question

Comment: @BenVoigt: you are right, my question is not about the span or the general logic... it is why there is a performance difference between Contains and IndexOf ...

Comment: Have you tested with a non-empty input (but that also doesn't contain the separator)?

Comment: At least for .NE 4.8 this seems unlikely, as `Contains` is implemented by calling `IndexOf` (see https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs). I doubt that this is different for .NET 4,6,2

Comment: Also, `Contains` calls `IndexOf`, so the performance difference is an artifact of your testing regimen.   https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L2172

Comment: @BenVoigt: So you say  it is a measurement error? it is a 70% error... are you sure? this sounds too simple root cause

Comment: @NirMH: Is your input the empty string?  Have you tried testing with a non-empty input that doesn't match?  It's easy for measurement noise to be 70% of zero...

Comment: @BenVoigt: Tested with input `FGH`. the Opt method runs 46.008ns while the regular 40.016ns. again the Contains is better than IndexOf

Comment: @NirMH: Are you aware there are other reasons for one method to be faster than another unrelated to the methods they call internally?

Comment: Please show the ildasm output for both functions.  I have a suspicion what's causing the "unoptimized" version to run slower.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think this is the help I am seeking - what mechanisms / other reasons can explain this?

Comment: How can I show the 'ildasm'?

Comment: You're compiling this code into an assembly (DLL or EXE file) right?  Run the ildasm tool that comes with .NET on that file.

Comment: But I think the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55432110/103167   If the "unoptimized" method gets inlined and the "optimized" one doesn't, then the cost of an extra function call will tip the scales.

Comment: You might try this one as well: `public string GetSubNameOpt2(string name)
{ var index = name.IndexOf(Separator, StringComparison.Ordinal); if (index >= 0) { return name.Substring(0, index); } return "INVALID"; }`

Comment: Did you measure a Debug build or a Release build?

Comment: It's subtle but I can reproduce this effect, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ahLC9T.  When the separator string is not found and the methods `return "INVALID";`, the unoptimized version is a trifle faster.  But if the separator string is found the optimized version is much faster, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/gTUbf7.

Comment: Incidentally, your unoptimized and optimized methods **return different results** when the `name` string contains a single `:` preceding a double `::`.  Given the input string `"a:b::c"` the first method returns `a` while the optimized version returns `a:b`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/gTUbf7.

Comment: @dbc: Pointed out much earlier (third comment)

Comment: @BenVoigt - ah so it is.  Comment thread is so long I missed it.

Comment: @dbc I get even better results when using `AsSpan().IndexOf` https://dotnetfiddle.net/gTUbf7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`string.Contains(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-7.0#system-string-contains(system-string)) (i.e. without explicitly specified `StringComparison`) is a very special beast in recent implementations of .NET and looks [something like the following](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f64dac2b57890aa53f39c26f6f88c5d85621f9e8/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Searching.cs#L11):

```
public bool Contains(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.value);
 
    return SpanHelpers.IndexOf(
        ref _firstChar,
        Length,
        ref value._firstChar,
        value.Length) >= 0;
}
```

While the `string.Contains(string, StringComparison)` overload just call `IndexOf`:

```
public bool Contains(string value, StringComparison comparisonType)
{
    return IndexOf(value, comparisonType) >= 0;
}
```

i.e. `name.Contains(Separator, StringComparison.Ordinal)` will result in "expected" performance.

And `IndexOf` for ordinal comparison currently uses internal [`Ordinal.IndexOf`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f64dac2b57890aa53f39c26f6f88c5d85621f9e8/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Globalization/Ordinal.cs#L256) which contains quite a lot of checks and different optimizations for more general use-case.

One thing you can try is using `AsSpan().IndexOf` which on my machine results in better performance for the optimized version:

```
public string name { get; set; } = "qwerty";
private const string Separator = "::";
private char[] SeparatorChars = Separator.ToCharArray();

[Benchmark]
public string GetSubName()
{
    if (name.Contains(Separator))
    {
        return name.Split(SeparatorChars)[0];
    }
    
    return "INVALID";
}

[Benchmark]
public string GetSubNameOpt()
{
    var index = name.AsSpan().IndexOf(SeparatorChars);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        return name.AsSpan().Slice(0, index).ToString();
    }
    
    return "INVALID";
}
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GetSubName | 8.850 ns | 0.2388 ns | 0.3856 ns |
| GetSubNameOpt | 8.430 ns | 0.2337 ns | 0.2400 ns |

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that by default, `IndexOf(string needle)` uses `StringComparison.CurrentCulture` which is almost certainly going to be lower performance than `StringComparison.Ordinal`.  And probably also not what the code author wants, unless the two strings happen to be localized text strings.